# Fastkml and UTF-8?

Tags: python

I'm trying to use [fastkml](https://fastkml.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to read/write KML files, but it seems like lxml, which it uses to parse XML, has something about UTF-8:

```
from fastkml import kml
from lxml import etree

INPUT_KML_FILE = "myfile.kml"

with open(INPUT_KML_FILE, 'rb') as myfile:
    #AttributeError: 'bytes' object has no attribute 'encode'
    #data=myfile.read().encode('utf-8')

    data=myfile.read()
k = kml.KML()
#ValueError
k.from_string(data)
```

What work-around would you suggest?

Thank you.

---

Edit: I tried with another KML file, and it ran OK. Too bad FastKML/lxml doesn't say which line in the KML file isn't to its liking.

```
INPUT_KML_FILE = "myotherfile.kml"

k = kml.KML()
with open(INPUT_KML_FILE,'rb') as kmlFile:
    k.from_string(kmlFile.read()) 
print(k.to_string(prettyprint=True))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this one. The b stands for binary and does not need to be encoded.

```
with io.open(name, 'r', encoding='utf-8') as file:
    data = file.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

*(Leaving additional details for similar fastkml-utf 8 related doubts).*

- When you are reading a KML File :

  ```
   with os.open(name, 'r') as kmlFile:
        k = kml.KML()
        k.from_string(kmlFile.read().encode('utf-8'))
  ```
- When you are reading a KML string :
  (Let doc be the KML string)

> k.from_string(doc.encode('utf-8'))

These are guaranteed to work.

Also, fastKML is built using lxml library, so you don't need to use lxml.etree .

If you have further Fastkml related doubts, you can check out the following article : https://medium.com/@wwaryan/the-definite-only-guide-to-fastkml-58b8e19b8454?source=friends_link&sk=3537cbf9c2fd8d426feb95d4062c8516